# How to put a text file into an array using CSV and then search for a specific value within that array

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to extract the decimal value from a text document using the CSV module but I am finding it difficult. Here is the text file I am using:

```
Lipids,1.2
Triglycerides,1.7
Fats,6.6
Sugar,7.1
```

and here is the code that I made but I am still trying to get it to work, I am finding it hard to search for the specific value. I don't think my idea of dividing arrays works :

```
searcher=Fats
with open('Truffles.txt','rU') as f:
    reader= csv.reader(f)
    #(reader) should look like this [Lipids,1.12],[Triglycerides,1.7]
    rows(1-4)=reader/4
    #So now row1=[Lipids,1.12] as reader as been divided into four parts
    if searcher in row1:
    num=row1/2 #The second part of row1
    else 
    #Move to row2 and continue search
    print (num)
    #Eventually num will be found.In this case 6.6 should be printed.
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is to create a long array (return) which contains all the data from the text file. Then the long array should get broken down into small, almost mini arrays (rows). Then the program should print the float value related to the string that was asked to be searched for (searcher).

Comment: CVS is a totally different thing to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax errors in that code. You can't write code by inventing your own syntax, like `rows(1-4)=reader/4`. You need to use the facilities that the language provides. But anyway...

The `csv` module is designed to let you loop over a CSV file row by row, and with your data file each row list will have two items: the compound name, and the associated float value. Here's a simple demo that performs the search you want. When it finds the item, it prints it and breaks out of the loop. If it doesn't find the item it tells you it can't be found.

```
import csv

searcher = 'Fats'
with open('Truffles.txt','rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == searcher:
            print('{}: {}'.format(*row))
            break
    else:
        print(searcher, 'not found')
```

**output**

```
Fats: 6.6
```